# Error while executing command inside script

Tags: bash

On ubuntu 18.10 I've problem with a simple script.

If I execute this command directly from shell it works:

```
drush -y rsync @d8.live:web/sites/default/files @self:sites/default --delete -vv
```

If I create a .sh script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
drush -y rsync @d8.live:web/sites/default/files @self:sites/default --delete -vv
```

The script doesn't work and the `drush` command returns me an error:

> The "--delete" option does not exist.

The command and the script are running from the same directory and the same user.

Where is the problem?

PS: "`drush`" is a wrapper that executes a docker-compose command

[EDIT]

```
$ type -a drush
drush ha "drush --strict=0" come alias
drush è /usr/local/bin/drush


$ cat /usr/local/bin/drush
#!/bin/bash
cd $PWD
docker-compose -p example exec --user 82 php drush $@
```

Comment: `drush` is an alias or a function? It won't work for the former, because aliases by default are not expanded in non-interactive shells.

Comment: What does `type -a drush` say in your shell?

Comment: `"drush" is a wrapper that executes a docker-compose command` show it.

Comment: I've edited the question, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases don't get expanded in scripts.  If you want the script to include `--strict=0` in the command line, you have to say so explicitly in the script.

Comment: unless maybe using `shopt -s expand_aliases` but i agree alias are not needed in a script, the only interest is in interactive shell

Comment: ... or `source ~/.bash_aliases` (even if I think that's ugly)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul It's worth mentioning, but the proper solution is really to have scripts which are independent of aliases (and probably to not use aliases a lot at all).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here:

```
$ type -a drush
drush ha "drush --strict=0" come alias
drush è /usr/local/bin/drush
```

the drush command is within your PATH environmental variable.

Now please make sure that /usr/local/bin folder is part of your `PATH variable, e.g. by:

```
$ tr : "\n" <<<$PATH | grep usr.local.bin
/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: If `type` was able to find the executable, it is by definition already on your `PATH`